# Why does pickle.dumps call __getattr__?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

```
import cPickle

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {'bar': 'baz'}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        assert hasattr(self, '_data')
        return self._data[name]

    # I even had to define this just to stop KeyError: '__getstate__'
    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__

foo = Foo()
bar = cPickle.dumps(foo)
cPickle.loads(bar)
```

This raises an assertion error.

I thought `pickle`/`cPickle` just turns `__dict__` into a string when dumping and then uses that string to set the `__dict__` of the new object directly when loading. Why would `dumps` need to call `bar.__getattr__`? How can I change `Foo` to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the documentation for cPickle: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

```
object.__getstate__()
```

> Classes can further influence how their instances are pickled; if the class defines the method `__getstate__()`, it is called and the return state is pickled as the contents for the instance, instead of the contents of the instance’s dictionary. If there is no `__getstate__()` method, the instance’s `__dict__` is pickled.
>
> Note
>
> At unpickling time, some methods like `__getattr__()`,
>   `__getattribute__()`, or `__setattr__()` may be called upon the instance. In case those methods rely on some internal invariant being true, the
>   type should implement either `__getinitargs__()` or `__getnewargs__()` to
>   establish such an invariant; otherwise, neither `__new__()` nor
>   `__init__()` will be called.

Since you are trying to assert that `hasattr(self, '_data')` is True, I believe that you need to use `__getinitargs__()` or `__getnewargs__()`. This is because when using pickle, a classes `__init__` method is not called.