# Pickle of object with __getattr__ method in Python returns `TypeError, object not callable`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I wanted to define a class that returns `None` for unknown attributes with `__getattr__` method.

After doing that, I am trying to dump an object of that class to a Pickle.

However, I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\SVN\Scripts\Rally\examples\t_pickle_None.py", line 14, in <module>
    pickle.dump(toto, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Without defining `__getattr__`, it works fine, but I would like to keep this function.

Here is my code: how to make it work with `__getattr__`?

Thanks

```
import pickle
from typing import Any

class Toto:
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __getattr__(self, _: str) -> Any:
        """Return None for all unknown attributes"""
        return None

toto = Toto("Toto")
with open('toto.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(toto, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: You need to be careful pickling objects that define a `__getattr__`. I wrote something about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158865/4014959). Does it help?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380224/how-to-make-classes-with-getattr-pickable and the links there.

Comment: @PM2Ring Interseting share, although the answer of Aran-Fey appared much clearer (especially at midnight when eyes are half closed :) Thanks

Comment: I agree that Aran-Fey's answer is good, in fact I already upvoted it. :) But I figured that those links had good relevant info, even if they didn't exactly answer your question. If they _did_ answer your question then I would have closed it as a duplicate. :)

Comment: Indeed. I like your idea of `UserDict`. I tried to make it work for my other problem of `mypy` complaining about dynamically created outputs but `mypy` complains also about your code :) ... but this is a topic for another day (or more specifically another question).

Comment: I don't blame `mypy` complaining about my code, it's pretty gnarly. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that pickle tries to check if your object has a [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) method, which can be used to customize how objects are pickled. Because your class doesn't define a `__getstate__` method, your `__getattr__` method ends up being called and it returns `None`. Pickle tries to call this `None` value and that produces the exception you got.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Define a `__getstate__` and corresponding `__setstate__` method in your class:

   ```
   def __getstate__(self):
       return vars(self)

   def __setstate__(self, state):
       vars(self).update(state)
   ```
2. Rewrite your `__getattr__` method to handle dunder-attributes better (i.e. throwing an AttributeError instead of returning a nonsense value):

   ```
   def __getattr__(self, attr: str) -> Any:
       """Return None for all unknown attributes"""
       if attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__'):
           raise AttributeError
       return None
   ```

Comment: Missing parens after AttributeError

Answer (score 2):

If you override `__getattr__`, you have tell how exactly your object can be pickled by implementing the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods

Have a look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for more info

```
>>> import pickle
>>> class Toto:
...     def __init__(self, name:str):
...         self.name = name
...     def __getattr__(self, _: str):
...         """Return None for all unknown attributes"""
...         return None
...     def __getstate__(self): return self.__dict__
...     def __setstate__(self, d): self.__dict__.update(d)
... 
>>> 
>>> t=Toto()
>>> pickle.dumps(t)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nToto\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00abcq\x04sb.'
>>>
```